# Including Vuetify code in TypeScript project prints lots of errors

Tags: typescript, vuetify.js

I'm building an app with the VueJS + TypeScript + WebPack + ESLint + VuetifyJS stack using @vue/cli.

Everything ok, until I wrote this include :

```js
import { TableHeader } from 'vuetify/src/components/VDataTable/mixins/header';
```

I did that because I wanted to have type hints on a method that works on these headers object.

With this import line, the project seems to works, but I'm getting a very long list of errors (several hundreds), from TypeScript I suppose, and related to files that belong to vuetify sources. Here is an example of error:

```js
ERROR in /home/mistiru/dev/chrono-tracker/node_modules/vuetify/src/util/ThemeProvider.ts(15,31):
15:31 Property 'rootIsDark' does not exist on type 'CombinedVueInstance<Vue, unknown, unknown, { isDark: boolean; }, Readonly<{ root: boolean; }>>'.
    13 |   computed: {
    14 |     isDark (): boolean {
  > 15 |       return this.root ? this.rootIsDark : Themeable.options.computed.isDark.call(this)
       |                               ^
    16 |     },
    17 |   },
    18 |
```

Did I include the wrong thing?

---

**EDIT**: My configuration is already as highlighted in the comment from @Rie. The project works, I have access to my dev site and I can use all the implemented features, it's just that these errors appear in the terminal, and I don't know why (and they might hide errors related to my potential mistakes...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I did not import the right thing.

By doing:

```js
import { DataTableHeader } from 'vuetify';
```

I don't know why, but the errors do not appear anymore.

I don't understand why it's called DataTableHeader, whereas it's called TableHeader in the online documentation.

Answer (score 3):

In a TypeScript Vuetify project you need to add `"vuetify"` to the `types` in your `tsconfig.json` and adjust the `plugins/vuetify.ts`.

tsconfig.json:

```
"types": [
  "webpack-env",
  "vuetify"
]
```

plugins/vuetify.ts:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuetify from "vuetify/lib";

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: "mdi"
  }
});
```

If you are using VS Code you might need to restart it to recognize the changes. You can then check isDark by using `this.$vuetify.theme.dark`.

Comment: I've already done these two steps, and using webstorm, but the problem is not related to the IDE as it shows those errors when I run `npm run serve` (that uses vue-cli-service serve)